# How to remove the negative sign in a list?

Tags: python, list, negative-number

I'm trying to remove all the negative signs before `index[2]` in `premier_league`:

**My code:**

```
premier_league = [
             ['A1','Manchester City', '-1', 'Aguero'],
             ['A2','Manchester City', '-11,2', 'Mahrez'],
             ['A3','Manchester City', '-13,5', 'Sterling'],
             ['B1','Liverpool', '-,5', 'Mane'],
             ['B2','Liverpool', '-5,6', 'Salah'],
             ['B3','Liverpool', '-7,2', 'Jota']]

for l in premier_league:
    del l[-2][0]
```

**Current output:**

```
TypeError: 'str' object doesn't support item deletion
```

**Desired output:**

```
premier_league = [
             ['A1','Manchester City', '1', 'Aguero'],
             ['A2','Manchester City', '11,2', 'Mahrez'],
             ['A3','Manchester City', '13,5', 'Sterling'],
             ['B1','Liverpool', ',5', 'Mane'],
             ['B2','Liverpool', '5,6', 'Salah'],
             ['B3','Liverpool', '7,2', 'Jota']]
```

Comment: Have you tried using a substring? eg `l[-2] = [-2][1:]`

Comment: strings are immuteable - you cannot change it - you can only replace the whole string by something different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.strip()` will remove whitespace from either side of the string you call it on. You can optionally give it a string, and it will remove all of those characters from either side of the string.

Its derivatives, `str.lstrip()` and `str.rstrip()`, will do the same but only for the left or right end of the string, respectively. In this case, since you want to remove a minus sign from the front, `str.lstrip()` is the way to go.

```
for l in premier_league:
    l[2] = l[2].lstrip('-')
```

Comment: Thank you bro. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re
premier_league = [[re.sub(r'^-', '', item) for item in x] for x in premier_league]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use str.strip() or you can convert to list and slice the "-"

```
for l in premier_league:
    if l[2].startswith('-'): #not sure if all start with - or not
       temp=list(l[2])[1:] #convert to list and slice
       l[2]=''.join(temp) #to return it to string again
```

side note: I think Liverpool should be first in your list, always ;)